# Get the closest dates from a query

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have this query:

```
   SELECT curr.slug,
            format((curr.senaste*100 / NULLIF(prev.senaste, 0)-100),1) as percentage
            FROM       aktier AS curr
            INNER JOIN aktier AS prev
                    ON curr.slug = prev.slug
            WHERE      date(prev.timestamp) = DATE(:from_date)
            AND        date(curr.timestamp) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
            AND        curr.slug = :slug
```

This query calculates the percentage change in a value between two dates from table `aktier`.

But  the thing is, that the table `aktier` is updated twice a day. And I have currently added an `INTERVAL -1 DAY` so I know I will get a value, and don't need to wait 24h to get a value. Is it possible to add that the `prev.timestamp` gets the "lowest date"- and time, and the `and` clause for `curr.timestamp` get the "highest".

So if the table is updated at `2015-11-24 12:30:00` and `2015-11-24 19:00:00` the prev.timestamp will retrieve its data from the 12.30 update, and curr.timestamp from 19.00. (Notice the `CURDATE()`).

So the minimum value I will get if it has only been one update is a NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

Crude way is doing a pair of sub queries to get the rows, one with a limit of 1 to get the latest and the other LIMIT 2,1 the get the 2nd latest.

As follows, assuming that there is only 1 record for curr and 1 for prev

```
SELECT curr.slug,
            format((curr.senaste*100 / NULLIF(prev.senaste, 0)-100),1) as percentage
FROM       
(
    SELECT *
    FROM aktier 
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS curr
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM aktier 
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 2, 1
) AS prev
ON curr.slug = prev.slug
WHERE     curr.slug = :slug
```